# Implementing an increment(+1) filed security using security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to be able to protect my increment logic from being abused from the front end
my current frond end code

```js
 // Initial Payload
const surfacePayload: SurfacePayload = {
        gender: selected.gender,
        unit: unit.current,
         // will increment the count in db by +1
        count: increment(+1),
        src: currentUser?.uid!,
     };
await setDoc(doc(db, docRef, surfacePayload);
```

my security rules logic is like the following :

```js
// requestData.count types 
request.resource.data.count is number && // if the incoming count is a number
request.resource.data.count <= 12 && // this field cannot exceed 12
```

my big concern however is the this counter is set as a protector for creating docs in a related sub-collection, and it is really ease to keep sending 0 or 1 there is no real check whether the incoming data are only (increment +1)added  to the current state of the count in doc... is there any other check that I can implement to make it rock solid, I tried to check again the current state using only (resource.data) but since this check is a part of a bigger check and it is chained so it has failed..

Comment: You can check if incoming value (`request.resource.data.count`) is _exactly_ 1 more than existing value (`resource.data.count`). See linked answer for more information. i.e. `request.resource.data.count == resource.data.count + 1;`

Comment: @Dharmaraj the isse is that the collection could not be exiting to begin with ..... so there is no way to look to check fro the src .. any idea ?

Comment: In addition to checking "just" whether the count increments by 1, you can even use [`getAfter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.getAfter) and `getBefore` (or `existsAfter`/`existsBefore`) to ensure that the increment only happens when a new document was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where your document might not exists at first place, you can write separate rules for `create` and `update` as shown below:

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.count == 1; // default value 1
allow update: if request.resource.data.count == resource.data.count + 1;
```

Comment: is there any way to tackle the decrement by -1 in update case as well , while keeping it secure ? Or is this an only one way solution ?